how to set proxy for tRest component in talend
i'm trying to set proxy for tRest component but its not working.
i have used tsetProxy component before tRest component.
in tRest Component we dont have to set proxy for execution like we have option in tRestClient.
Proxy should set before tRest component.

You should use the tRestClient component, there is a Proxy HTTP option in advanced parameters
